# Why does ovirt VM using ceph disk stay in "waiting for launch" status

Tags: ceph, ovirt, cinder

My setup comprises of ceph mimic (centos 7, setup with ceph-ansible), cinder/keystone combo on pike release, and ovirt 4.2.5.1.

The external cinder provider is setup and I can create disks.

When creating a vm and starting it, the VM shows up in the ovirt dashboard as "wait for launch"

on the ovirt node, that is supposed to run the VM I checked libvirt:

```
# virsh --readonly list

 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
14    testceph                       paused
```

checking the domain configuration also seems ok... Most important the ceph mons are given in the disk configuration.

```
# virsh --readonly dumpxml

<domain type='kvm' id='15'>
  <name>testceph</name>
  <uuid>036a2385-2b4f-48f9-bcf9-8f2882ecde36</uuid>
  <metadata xmlns:ns0="http://ovirt.org/vm/tune/1.0" xmlns:ovirt-vm="http://ovirt.org/vm/1.0">
    <ns0:qos/>
    <ovirt-vm:vm xmlns:ovirt-vm="http://ovirt.org/vm/1.0">
    <ovirt-vm:clusterVersion>4.2</ovirt-vm:clusterVersion>
    <ovirt-vm:destroy_on_reboot type="bool">False</ovirt-vm:destroy_on_reboot>
    <ovirt-vm:launchPaused>false</ovirt-vm:launchPaused>
    <ovirt-vm:memGuaranteedSize type="int">2730</ovirt-vm:memGuaranteedSize>
    <ovirt-vm:minGuaranteedMemoryMb type="int">2730</ovirt-vm:minGuaranteedMemoryMb>
    <ovirt-vm:resumeBehavior>auto_resume</ovirt-vm:resumeBehavior>
    <ovirt-vm:startTime type="float">1535016868.02</ovirt-vm:startTime>
    <ovirt-vm:device mac_address="00:1a:4a:16:01:78">
        <ovirt-vm:specParams/>
        <ovirt-vm:vm_custom/>
    </ovirt-vm:device>
</ovirt-vm:vm>
  </metadata>
  <maxMemory slots='16' unit='KiB'>16777216</maxMemory>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static' current='1'>16</vcpu>
  <iothreads>1</iothreads>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <sysinfo type='smbios'>
    <system>
      <entry name='manufacturer'>oVirt</entry>
      <entry name='product'>oVirt Node</entry>
      <entry name='version'>7-5.1804.el7.centos.2</entry>
      <entry name='serial'>49434D53-0200-9031-2500-31902500FB7F</entry>
      <entry name='uuid'>036a2385-2b4f-48f9-bcf9-8f2882ecde36</entry>
    </system>
  </sysinfo>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.3.0'>hvm</type>
    <smbios mode='sysinfo'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='partial'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>Nehalem</model>
    <topology sockets='16' cores='1' threads='1'/>
    <numa>
      <cell id='0' cpus='0' memory='4194304' unit='KiB'/>
    </numa>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='variable' adjustment='0' basis='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' error_policy='report'/>
      <source file='/rhev/data-center/mnt/192.168.10.6:_media_ovirt-cd-images/c394242c-81ae-4d6a-a193-65157cc84702/images/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/ubuntu-server-18.04.iso' startupPolicy='optional'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <alias name='ua-fcca0dff-d833-4f28-b782-78ce0b016afe'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='network' device='disk' snapshot='no'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' error_policy='stop' io='threads'/>
      <auth username='cinder'>
        <secret type='ceph' uuid='c6020051-6cd3-4ddf-982e-3d94c080de9c'/>
      </auth>
      <source protocol='rbd' name='volumes/volume-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f'>
        <host name='192.168.20.21' port='6789'/>
        <host name='192.168.20.22' port='6789'/>
        <host name='192.168.20.23' port='6789'/>
      </source>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <serial>9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f</serial>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <alias name='ua-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='piix3-uhci'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0'>
      <alias name='scsi0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='00:1a:4a:16:01:78'/>
      <source bridge='ovirtmgmt'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <filterref filter='vdsm-no-mac-spoofing'/>
      <link state='up'/>
      <mtu size='1500'/>
      <alias name='ua-446090cf-6758-4b3d-bd87-eb8b61442a46'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channels/036a2385-2b4f-48f9-bcf9-8f2882ecde36.ovirt-guest-agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='ovirt-guest-agent.0'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channels/036a2385-2b4f-48f9-bcf9-8f2882ecde36.org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <alias name='channel1'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </channel>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <alias name='channel2'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5900' tlsPort='5901' autoport='yes' listen='192.168.10.11' passwdValidTo='1970-01-01T00:00:01'>
      <listen type='network' address='192.168.10.11' network='vdsm-ovirtmgmt'/>
      <channel name='main' mode='secure'/>
      <channel name='display' mode='secure'/>
      <channel name='inputs' mode='secure'/>
      <channel name='cursor' mode='secure'/>
      <channel name='playback' mode='secure'/>
      <channel name='record' mode='secure'/>
      <channel name='smartcard' mode='secure'/>
      <channel name='usbredir' mode='secure'/>
    </graphics>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5902' autoport='yes' listen='192.168.10.11' keymap='en-us' passwdValidTo='1970-01-01T00:00:01'>
      <listen type='network' address='192.168.10.11' network='vdsm-ovirtmgmt'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='32768' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='ua-31537f3a-f1cf-4269-839c-bc82721ff7f3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <stats period='5'/>
      <alias name='ua-beeefd9c-c2bd-4836-83f0-a28657219b3e'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model='virtio'>
      <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend>
      <alias name='ua-7d25e1b5-4d03-4bc3-80f6-83a80d69b391'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux' relabel='yes'>
    <label>system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c565,c625</label>
    <imagelabel>system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c565,c625</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+107:+107</label>
    <imagelabel>+107:+107</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

And yes. I can see the ovirt node and the ceph node talk to each other. But the ovirt node is only talking to the ceph monitor. There is no OSD involved. Both nodes can talk to each other, jumbo frames are allowed and working. In this output the ceph monitor is 192.168.20.21 and the ovirt node is 192.168.20.11

```
[root@ceph1 ~]# tcpflow -c -i enp3s0 src or dst host 192.168.20.11
tcpflow: listening on enp3s0
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44734: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44734-192.168.020.021.06789: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44734-192.168.020.021.06789: *D
192.168.020.011.44734-192.168.020.021.06789:
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44734:
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44736: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44736-192.168.020.021.06789: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44736-192.168.020.021.06789: *D
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44736:
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44738: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44738-192.168.020.021.06789: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44738-192.168.020.021.06789: *D!
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44738:
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44740: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44740-192.168.020.021.06789: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44740-192.168.020.021.06789: *D"
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44740:
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44742: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44742-192.168.020.021.06789: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44742-192.168.020.021.06789: *D#
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44742:
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44754: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44754-192.168.020.021.06789: ceph v027
192.168.020.011.44754-192.168.020.021.06789: *D)
192.168.020.021.06789-192.168.020.011.44754:
```

And this goes on and on until the qemu log on the ovirt nodes shows:

```
2018-08-23T09:34:31.233493Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=rbd:volumes/volume-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f:id=cinder:auth_supported=cephx\;none:mon_host=192.168.20.21\:6789\;192.168.20.22\:6789\;192.168.20.23\:6789,file.password-secret=ua-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f-secret0,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-ua-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f,serial=9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f,cache=none,werror=stop,rerror=stop,aio=threads: 'serial' is deprecated, please use the corresponding option of '-device' instead
2018-08-23T09:39:31.281126Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=rbd:volumes/volume-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f:id=cinder:auth_supported=cephx\;none:mon_host=192.168.20.21\:6789\;192.168.20.22\:6789\;192.168.20.23\:6789,file.password-secret=ua-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f-secret0,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-ua-9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f,serial=9b95b28c-9eec-4110-9973-88c161d3503f,cache=none,werror=stop,rerror=stop,aio=threads: 
error connecting: Connection timed out
2018-08-23 09:39:31.291+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
```

So what keeps ovirt and ceph keep from talking ? The image introduction via cinder is done, but somehow ovirt is not contacting the ceph osds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the librbd1 library that is coming along with centos 7 which is the base of oVirt 4.2.x. It is too old to play along with ceph V13.x aka mimic and probably also V12 luminous.

See [this post](https://lists.ovirt.org/archives/list/users@ovirt.org/thread/R4U5PHBAM5KXU73CDWOVMKWKUYZM2SKI/#Q7I6KVGELTU7CTDV3FPVIEZMXHJ3VPZ2) from the oVirt forms for a discussion about this problem.

[There is a way](https://serverfault.com/questions/927821/how-to-upgrade-librbd1-and-librados2-for-ovirt-4-2-x-node-ng) to upgrade the libraries.